# Sum a range of ints in a List

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, linq, lambda

Let's say I have a List like this:

```
List<string> _lstr = new List<string>();

        _lstr.Add("AA");
        _lstr.Add("BB");
        _lstr.Add("1");
        _lstr.Add("7");
        _lstr.Add("2");
        _lstr.Add("5");
```

How do I sum up the integers in the List if I don't know how many integers are in the List? Could be 4, could be 10, etc... All I know is that the first two items are strings, the rest are integers.

In this case the desired result is **15**.

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you made any attempts to solve this problem yourself?  Do you know how to validate if a string can be parsed to an integer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Method A** Unconditionally skips the first 2 and assumes the rest are all integer strings:

```
var sum = _lstr.Skip(2).Select(int.Parse).Sum();
```

**Method B** Makes no assumtions:

```
var sum = _lstr.Aggregate(0, (x, z) => x + (int.TryParse(z, out x) ? x : 0));
```

Answer (score 4):

without making the assumption that *first two items are strings*

```
int sum = _lstr.Select(s => {int i; return int.TryParse(s,out i) ? i : 0; })
               .Sum();
```

Comment: +1 for the no-assumptions approch. Assumptions are often wrong

Answer (score 1):

Very easily:

```
list.Skip(2).Select(int.Parse).Sum();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var sum = _lstr.Skip(2).Sum(s => int.Parse(s));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 int num = 0; int sum  = 0;
 _lstr.ForEach(x => {Int32.TryParse(x, out num); sum +=num;});
```

Just to prove the point that if Int32.TryParse fails the out var is resetted to zero

```
 _lstr.Add("AA");
 _lstr.Add("BB");
 _lstr.Add("1");
 _lstr.Add("7");
 _lstr.Add("2");
 _lstr.Add("5");
 _lstr.Add("CC");
 _lstr.Add("9");

 int num = 0; int sum  = 0;
 foreach(string s in _lstr)
 {
    bool result = Int32.TryParse(s, out num);
    Console.WriteLine("TryParse:" + result + " num=" + num);
 }

TryParse:False num=0
TryParse:False num=0
TryParse:True num=1
TryParse:True num=7
TryParse:True num=2
TryParse:True num=5
TryParse:False num=0
TryParse:True num=9
```

Comment: but in case of false num=0, try adding another string and another integer after the last integer

Comment: Apologies, it's `out`, so it has to change the value - are you confident that it sets it to 0? I can't find any documentation to that effect.

Comment: @Steve I am not the downvoter, but I personally don't like much using Linq with side-effects.

Comment: Yeah, I like this, could do with an explanation though.

Comment: @L.B Technically it's not even LINQ.  There is no LINQ at all in this answer.

Comment: @Servy than a classical for loop would seem better(of course just preference).

Comment: @VisualMelon, added an example of Int32.TryParse behavior

Answer (score -5):

```
int sum=0,i=0;       
foreach(string s in mylist){
    //in case of non integers
    try{
        i=int.parse(s);//you can put convert or tryparse too here
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        i=0;
    }
    sum=sum+i;
}

return sum;
```

Comment: Because it doesn't work.  The OP has a list of strings, not all of which are integers.

Comment: well i gave the general idea, thats what we get on forums generally anyways i guess OP has his problem solved by now.

Comment: Exceptions should be used to handle exceptions not workflows.

Comment: You must avoid the try/catch, there is the `int.TryParse`.

Comment: which is mentioned in comments of given code ,its programming choice to simplify understanding

Comment: @Alok You mention on the comments but you have it with try/catch. Always avoid that especial inside that loop, you end up with very slow code.